# Real world X.509 v2 certificate examples?

Tags: x.509

Just out of curiosity, could you provide (old) real world X.509 v2 certificate examples that include the deprecated (in some version of X.509) and forbidden (in RFC 5280) `issuerUniqueIdentifier` or `subjectUniqueIdentifier` fields?.

A bonus point would be pointing at any application, library or whatever capable of generating such type of certificates.

Note: A similar question is asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788244/how-to-create-a-legacy-v1-or-v2-x-509-cert-for-testing.